# Entity Framework not creating extra columns in join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can somebody explain why Entity Framework will not create extra columns `CurVal` and `NewVal` in join table? It is creating a join table with `DeviceFeatureID` and `UserDeviceID`.

```
public class DeviceFeature
{
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int DeviceFeatureID { get; set; }

        [Required]        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserDevice> UserDevices { get; set; }
}

public class UserDevice
{
        public int UserDeviceID { get; set; }
        public int DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set;}

        public virtual ICollection<DeviceFeature> DeviceFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class UserDeviceFeatureStatus
{
        public int UserDeviceID { get; set; }
        public int DeviceFeatureID { get; set; }

        public virtual UserDevice UserDevice { get; set; }
        public virtual DeviceFeature DeviceFeature { get; set; }

        public string CurVal { get; set; }
        public string NewVal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your DbContext

Comment: Roy, this is my dbcontextpublic. Sorry i think i need to learn how to format code in reply.


class IOTWebContext : DbContext
    {
       
    
        public IOTWebContext() : base("name=IOTWebContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<IOTWeb.Models.DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<IOTWeb.Models.DeviceFeature> DeviceFeatures { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<IOTWeb.Models.UserDevice> UserDevices { get; set; }



    }

Comment: @Tom, better than a comment, just edit your question and add your DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

Your many-to-many relationship table is being generated automatically by your Virtual Collections an not by your entity.

You can either include the join entity in the DbContext (but it will probably duplicate the table unless you remove the virtual collections) or you can use the Fluent API to configure the relationship.

To do the later you will need to change your Virtual Collections to the ReleationShip type and add this to your OnModelCreating:

```cs
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserDeviceFeatureStatus>()
        .HasKey(t => new { t.UserDeviceID, t.DeviceFeatureID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDeviceFeatureStatus>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.UserDevice)
        .WithMany(p => p.DeviceFeatures) // from UserDevice
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserDeviceID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDeviceFeatureStatus>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.DeviceFeature)
        .WithMany(t => t.UserDevices) //from DeviceFeature
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.DeviceFeatureID);
```

In DeviceFeature

```cs
public virtual ICollection<UserDeviceFeatureStatus> UserDevices { get; set; }
```

In UserDevice

```cs
public virtual ICollection<UserDeviceFeatureStatus> DeviceFeatures { get; set; }
```

For more information about EF relationships you can see the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a many-to-many relationship between `UserDevice` and `DeviceFeature` through `UserDeviceFeatureStatus` than you need to have a navigation property from the 2 tables to your "join" table. I understand that you try to navigate directly from `UserDevice` to `DeviceFeature` directly and vice-versa. But you won't be able to do that in EF if your relationship table contains other fields than the primary keys of the tables you're trying to link.

You can try this:

```
public class DeviceFeature
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int DeviceFeatureID { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDeviceFeatureStatus> UserDeviceFeatureStatuses { get; set; }

}

public class UserDevice
{
    public int UserDeviceID { get; set; }
    public int DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<UserDeviceFeatureStatus> UserDeviceFeatureStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class UserDeviceFeatureStatus
{

    public int UserDeviceID { get; set; }
    public int DeviceFeatureID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDevice UserDevice { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceFeature DeviceFeature { get; set; }

    public string CurVal { get; set; }
    public string NewVal { get; set; }
}
```

So to navigate from `UserDevice` to `DeviceFeature` for example, you'll need to navigate to `UserDeviceFeatureStatus` first then from there to `DeviceFeature`.